# ​Do the Borg have the ability to sense changes/alterations in time?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-voyager

​Do the Borg have the ability to sense changes/alterations in time? With the new Season of *Picard* coming, it begs the question of will the Borg Queen also be aware of the changes.

Comment: When you say "changes in time", do you mean alterations to the timeline? Like Guinan sensing that something was wrong with the timeline in _Yesterday's Enterprise_? Also, can you specify who you mean by "she"?

Comment: Question Edited

Comment: Also, what changes are you referring to?

Comment: Worth noting that the ability as displayed by Guinan was originally written as a specific result of her having entered the Nexus, so it's not something that the Borg could assimilate, but could they have *replicated* the ability by entering the Nexus themselves?

Comment: @WolfieSmith Guninan's ability was oriignally unexplained in "Yesterdays's Enterprise" written years before STar trek: Generations, and would have been considered intrinsic to either her as an individual or her species.  And which canon production attributes it to her time the Nexus?

Comment: @Golding I was only referring to the original *Generations* script, which is the only written reference to where her ability came from, even if it was never filmed. I wasn't attempting to give a canonical answer, only adding to the discussion.

Comment: Pedant .. [Begging the question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begging_the_question).  Technically you mean "raising the question", although I am fighting against modern usage :(

Comment: People watch that show? It's certainly not Star Trek.

Comment: @HamSandwich Opinions are like buttocks - everyone has one.... I am of the opinion that this show is much more Star Trek than new movies or that abomination of an STD (where even abbreviation seems fitting).

Comment: Anything after Enterprise (and quite possibly Voyager) is probably not worth watching in my opinion. But that's just me. I'm not a fan of cash grabs. And Enterprise basically doesn't care a bit about continuity, which is annoying.

Comment: Yes the Borg Queen can sense changes in the timeline.